# Get the moving average considering relative proportions of variables in another column

Tags: r, moving-average

I want to get the moving average (e.g. using `movavg()`) and get the relative proportions of categorical variables from another column. For intance, take the following data frame:

```
data.frame('employee'=1:8, 'pastjob'=c('sales','sales admin','sales','sales admin','ops','ops','R&D','IT'), 'results'=c(150,200,250,300,125,150,175,150))
```

I want to get a simple moving average for every four values in the "results" column and get the relative proportions of "pastjob" in the other columns. So, the output would be:

225 - sales (50%), sales admin (50%), ops (0%), R&D (0%), IT(0%)

150 - sales (0%), sales admin (0%), ops (50%), R&D (25%), IT(25%)

Answer (score 1):

Hi just repace the 4 for the number of the size of the index

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- data.frame('employee'=1:8, 'pastjob'=c('sales','sales admin','sales','sales admin','ops','ops','R&D','IT'), 'results'=c(150,200,250,300,125,150,175,150))

df_example %>% 
  mutate(index = rep(1:(n()/4),each = 4)) %>% 
  group_by(index,pastjob) %>% 
  summarise(total_sales = sum(results),ns = n()) %>%
  mutate(prop = total_sales/sum(total_sales),
         group_mean = sum(total_sales)/sum(ns)) %>%
  select(index,pastjob,prop,group_mean) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = prop,names_from = pastjob,values_fill = 0)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'index'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#> # Groups:   index [2]
#>   index group_mean sales `sales admin`    IT   ops `R&D`
#>   <int>      <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1        225 0.444         0.556  0    0     0    
#> 2     2        150 0             0      0.25 0.458 0.292
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>